# In Mongodb how to understand the documentation for WriteResult when using collection.insert and Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to mongodb and new to Node and attempting to do an insert into a collection in the most careful way possible in order to fully understand how to make the best use of the documentation for mongodb.

The documentation for collection.insert states that for the mongo shell: WriteResult() is a wrapper that contains the result status of the mongo shell write methods. The MongoDB Manual 2.6  notes that  [db.collection.insert()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#db.collection.insert) returns: a WriteResult object for single inserts or a BulkWriteResult object for bulk inserts.

Is this only for the mongo shell and for the Java driver?

Some simple code to exercise insert Node.js is as follows:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb'),
  dbHost  = '127.0.0.1',
  dbPort  = 27017;

var Db = mongo.Db;
var Connection = mongo.Connection;
var Server = mongo.Server;
var db = new Db ('local', new Server(dbHost, dbPort), {w:1}); 

db.open(function(error, dbConnection){
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    console.log('db state: ', db._state);
    items = [ { name: 'John' }, { name: 'Joel'} ];
    dbConnection.collection('messages', {w:1}, function(error, coll){
        if (error) {
           console.error(error);
           process.exit(1);
        }
        coll.insert(items, function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
                process.exit(1);
            }
            console.info('created/inserted: ', result);
            db.close();
            process.exit(0);
        });
    });
});
```

This seems as straight forward as possible and IF a WriteResult is to be returned anywhere it would have to be in the callback inside insert in the Node.js way.  So my only conclusion is that the mongodb driver for Node.js does not provide a WriteResult.

Is there a good resource that makes this clearer, or do I have some misunderstanding?  Any thoughts/help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe this answer gives you a clue, it shows a way to obtain a WriteResult object from a bulk query: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26152907